# ngif which function cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

guys I m new to angular so ignore my silly question, let me show the first code

```
 <ion-row *ngFor="let data of totalagent">
          <ion-col col-3>
            <ion-row *ngIf="createTable(data)">
              <ion-col class="agent-header" col-12  style='color: white;text-align: center;display: block;'>{{data.host}}</ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col class="agent-name" col-6>{{data.name}}</ion-col>
                <ion-col class="agent-count" col-3>{{data.count}}</ion-col>
                <ion-col class="agent-avg" col-3>{{data.delay}}</ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-col>         
  </ion-row>
```

in my function like

```
createTable(params){
  if(this.prevAgent !== params.agent_name){
    this.prevAgent = params.agent_name;
    return true;
}
 else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

this above code is throw like "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'" can anyone tell me why it causing error

Comment: Because, all things being equal, two subsequent calls to your method should return the same value. Your method shouldn't call `this.prevAgent = params.agent_name`. It should **get** information, not set anything. The first time it's called, it sets the prevAgent and returns true. The second time it's called, it returns false. This is incorrect.

Comment: @JBNizet then any solution?

Comment: Well, just don't do that. Your method is supposed to decide whether or not  something should be displayed. That method shouldn't change its mind after it's been called once. If its result depends on the value of the data at the previous index in the array, then get the data at the previous index in the array and decide what to return. But don't modify the state of your component when taking that decision.

Comment: @JBNizet i m try to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55166227/how-dynamic-loop-set-one-header-and-multiple-body-in-ionic-and-angular so i m using a function at  "Ngif" to set it dynamically can you suggest some example with sample code?

Comment: I don't see how the the question you linked to has anything to do with the above code. In the question you linked to, you're trying to generate two separate tables, one per `host`, if I understand correctly. So you should have two arrays, and two tables in your template. Use TypeScript to group your rows by host. Then loop through the groups, and generate a table for each group.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for replay since i m new to angular so i don't know how to group rows by host using type script can you give some example it would be greate for me

Comment: Google is your friend. Google for "how to group JavaScript objects by property", and read.